# Oracle | Parsing a blob to get values

Tags: oracle, blob

I have an XML stored in BLOB in an Oracle Table. Like below:

```
   <SomeOtherTags>
   </SomeOtherTags>
   <SCH:DockDoorSettingDefs>
      <SCH:DockDoorSettingDef>
         <SCH:Name>ABC</SCH:Name>
         <SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
            <SCH:AppointmentCode>ABC_Code1</SCH:AppointmentCode>
         </SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
         <SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
            <SCH:AppointmentCode>ABC_Code2</SCH:AppointmentCode>
         </SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
         <SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
            <SCH:AppointmentCode>ABC_Code3</SCH:AppointmentCode>
         </SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
      </SCH:DockDoorSettingDef>
      <SCH:DockDoorSettingDef>
         <SCH:Name>PQR</SCH:Name>
         <SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
            <SCH:AppointmentCode>PQR_Code1</SCH:AppointmentCode>
         </SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
         <SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
            <SCH:AppointmentCode>PQR_Code2</SCH:AppointmentCode>
         </SCH:ReceivingAttribute>
      </SCH:DockDoorSettingDef>
    </SCH:DockDoorSettingDefs>
    <SomeOtherTags>
    </SomeOtherTags>
```

I want to query this blob column in such a way that it should parse the parameters in BLOB and display the result in below format. Can anyone help?

```
_____________________________________
|   NAME    |   Appointment Code    |
|___________|_______________________|
|   ABC     |   ABC_Code1           |
|   ABC     |   ABC_Code2           |
|   ABC     |   ABC_Code3           |
|   PQR     |   PQR_Code1           |
|   PQR     |   PQR_Code2           |
|___________|_______________________|
```

Comment: You're sure it's `BLOB` and not `CLOB`?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @KaushikNayak
Yes, it's a BLOB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract value present between XML tags from a blob in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51208429/extract-value-present-between-xml-tags-from-a-blob-in-oracle-sql)